# In Unity3D, what is the best way to offset the viewport with multiple resolutions so the player is always to the left edge?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm working on my latest project, which is a action sidescroller, primarily 2D but using a perspective camera for 3D effect. I've gotten the basics working - design, etc, and now fixing the camera so that it follows correctly. However, I'd like to keep the player on the left side of the viewport - not actually modifying the player's position, but the camera following an offset. I have it partially worked out, but it broke the moment I started playing around with other alternative resolutions - say, from web standard, standalone, to mobile devices. This is what I want to do:

[image]

This is my code attempt thus far. The camera itself works perfectly for basic up/down right scrolling, but when the resolution changes the player can vanish:

```
public Transform TrackTarget;
public float dampTime = 0.15f;
public bool Ready = false;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 TargetOffset = Vector3.zero;

void Start()
{
    TargetOffset = new Vector3(16,0,0);
    Vector3 point = TrackTarget.position + TargetOffset;
    Vector3 Destination = new Vector3(point.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.x);             
    transform.position = Destination; 
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    if (Ready) {
        if (TrackTarget)
        {
            Vector3 point = TrackTarget.position + TargetOffset;
            Vector3 Destination = new Vector3(point.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.x);             
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, Destination, ref velocity, dampTime);
        }
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Ready) {
        Vector3 CameraPosition = transform.position;
        CameraPosition.z = -30.00f;
        transform.position = CameraPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful.

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 5;
    public float heigt = 1;
    public float width = 6;
    public float damping = 5;

    void Start()
    {
       Vector3 unicornPos = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(target.position);

       width =  camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, camera.nearClipPlane)).x/3;
    }

    void LateUpdate () {

        Vector3 wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint (width, heigt, -distance);

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, wantedPosition, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    }
}
```